# Как сделать кликабельно из блока фигуру?

Tags: canvas, вёрстка, css

Есть кнопка меню НОВОСТИ ( это блок обведен красным) Как сделать что бы кликабельная была только синяя область?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть специальный тег: [area](http://htmlbook.ru/html/area)

Comment: Теперь мы знаем слово canvas, но забыли что такое area.

Comment: @istem теперь так модно. Использовать jQuery, чтобы получить высоту блока :)

Comment: Что будет через несколько лет? 
![alt text][1] ?


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/rsbUSEe.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Например, определять цвет в координате клика. Если цвет совпадает с синим - переходить по ссылке.

Comment: это на чем такое пишется? есть пример, или какие функции использовать?

Comment: для определения координаты клика мыши можно использовать jQuery  http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

Comment: у Вас вроде как в тегах стоит canvas. Чтобы определить координаты мышки - Вам дали ссылку. Чтобы определить цвет в координатах мышки:

var imData = ctx.getImageData(mouseX,mouseY,1,1)

//красная составляющая
var red = imData.data[0];
//зеленая составляющая
var green = imData.data[1];
//синяя составляющая
var blue = imData.data[2];

Comment: А если там не один цвет, а градиент?

Comment: @Heidel можно, но jQuery не определяет координаты, и даже не помогает в этом. В вашем варианте он лишь поможет проще выбрать элемент.